# How to construct a loop function for a massive data frame

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm trying to find **outliers** in many times series data frames by writing a **loop function** so that the result would be listed.

Every row usually has numbers or just zeros, but there are sometimes N/A values and they should be eliminated from the function.

For every row there is a **name of data (first column)** and then different numbers (further columns). For every data I find the **mean**, **standard deviation**, **Tmin** and **Tmax** and then simple filtering:

```
mean <- mean(as.vector(as.numeric(x2[1,])))
sd <-   sd(as.vector(as.numeric(x2[1,])))
Tmin <- mean - (3*sd)
Tmax <- mean + (3*sd)
x[which(x < Tmin | x > Tmax)]
```

Sample table:

| Name | 2015Q1 | 2015Q2 | 2015Q3 | 2015Q4 | 2016Q1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banking sect. | 63.4442 | 61.73465 | 67.33452 | 52.34546 | 12.3334 | ... |
| Money laund. sect. | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2.4 | 0 | ... |
| Households | N/A | N/A | 1.2 | N/A | 9.6 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Result after using the loop function should be a table containing only the *Name *column and *outlier* column and *values*.

I've tried writing a loop function, but I don't understand loop functions fully. It should be reusable adding new identical template data frames.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  mean <- mean(as.numeric(data.frame(x[i,2:50])))
  sd <-   sd(as.numeric(data.frame(x[i,2:50])))
  Tmin <- mean - (3*sd)
  Tmax <- mean + (3*sd)
  print(x[which(x < Tmin | x > Tmax)])
  i <- i+1
}
```

Would appreciate any advice.
Thank you

Comment: (1) Since it appears to me that an outlier can occur in any year, and you might have zero or more than one outlier, your output doesn't seem reasonable (or even feasible). (2) This sample data to me really screams reshaping, such as with columns `c("yearqtr", "sector", "value")` or less-long `c("yearqtr", "Banking", "MoneyLaund", "Households")` (I prefer the first for many reasons). This wide-format with "data in the column names" (year/quarter) is much less efficient for sector-grouped calculations, summaries, etc. The first (longer) format would make finding outliers much easier.

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, `for` loops should be avoided like the plague. Use the function `rowMeans` to compute the mean of each row, and use `apply` to find the `sd` of each row. Here's some experimental code:

```
df <- cbind(
    Name=sample(stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 1, "[A-Z]"), size=100, replace=T), 
    data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n=1000), nrow=100))
)

means <- rowMeans(as.numeric(df[, 2:ncol(df)], na.rm=T)
stdDevs <- apply(X=df[, 2:ncol(df), MARGIN=1, FUN=sd, na.rm=T)
Tmin <- means - 3*stdDevs
Tmax <- means + 3*stdDevs

outliers <- sapply(df, FUN=function(x){x<Tmin | x>Tmax})
```

This yields a boolean array, where each entry indicates whether that entry is an outlier. NOTE: the `sapply` function outputs `TRUE` for every entry in the `Name` column.

**EDIT**: details to get into the format OP desires.

```
outliers <- data.frame(sapply(df, FUN=function(x){x<Tmin | x>Tmax}))
outliers$Name <- df$Name
outliers <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
    outliers, names_to="variable", cols=setdiff(colnames(outliers), "Name")
)
outliers <- outliers[outliers$value == TRUE, ]
```

New you have a data frame where each row shows a `Name`-`variable` combination that is an outlier (according to the +/- three standard deviation rule you set forth).